# One to Many and Many to one

Tags: java, jpa

I have this situation and I wonder if I can make it using **JPA**, at the same time a **many to one** and **one to many** relationship,
I have a **Library** with a list of **Book** (**One to Many**) so i can insert a **book** in a **library**
At the same time I would like to **update** a **book** saying that now it belongs to another **library** just updating the **book** information (so it removes it from it's **library** and it puts it into another one)
Is this possible using **JPA** annotations?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible? Absolutely. What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing, for now I just have a library object with a list of books annotated with a onetomany, but i don't know how to do the other relationship, if i want to update a book now i must remove it from the first library and insert it into another one

Comment: oh ok sorry for my ignorance but how would I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mappedBy` in `@OneToMany`, for example:

```
@Entity
class Book {       

   @ManyToOne
   Library library

}

@Entity
class Library {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy='library')     
   List<Book> books

}
```

To add new objects, you can use something like:

```
Library library1 = new Library()
em.persist(library1)

Book book1 = new Book()
book1.library = library1
em.persist(book1)

Book book2 = new Book()
book2.library = library1
em.persist(book2)
```

For the `@OneToMany` side, you can still retrieve `books` from `library`, for example:

```
// in transaction
Library library = findLibraryById(1)
println library.books.size() // output: 2
```

You can then change `library` for a `Book` by simply setting new value for `library`, for example:

```
// in transaction
Library library2 = new Library()
em.persist(library2)
Book book = c.findBookById()
book.library = library2
```

UPDATE:  If you want to persist in one operation, you can use `cascade` in the mapping (not really recommended!), for example:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
Library library
```

Now operations on `Book` will be cascaded to `Library`, for example, creating a `Book` will also create its `Library`:

```
Library libraryA = new Library()
Book book = new Book()
book.library = libraryA
em.persist(book)
```

Beware that JPA doesn't maintain in-memory state of `Library.books` for you.  You should add the `Book` to `Library.books` manually, or reexecute query to obtain the up to date state of `Library`.

Another drawback is `Book` must know which `Library` it belong to.  This shouldn't be the responsibility of `Book`.  This will make maintenance harder in the future.  For example, if you decide to store `Book` in `BookRack` instead of `Library`, you'll need to change both `Book` and `Library`.

Comment: but ok just the example of updating a book to change it's library, so I must manually remove it from the first library, set it's new library and add it to the new library? all of this manually? and the persist the book and both libraries? no way to do it in a clean way?

Comment: *and the persist the book and both libraries? no way to do it in a clean way?* You can use `cascade` in `@ManyToOne`, see my updated answer.  But it is a bit strange, why must you create your `Library` everytime you have a `Book`?  In most apps, `Library` is created separately from `Book` (ex: in different screen).

Comment: *so I must manually remove it from the first library, set it's new library and add it to the new library? all of this manually?* JPA doesn't support such magic, see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side.  In this case, `Book` is the owner of the relationship.  It is your responsibility to update `Library.books` (usually by adding code in the setter).